# Changing email input filed name to user_email in register.blade in Laravel I get an error

Tags: laravel, registration, fortify

I am using Fortify, and I changed the email input field name to `user_email` and made the necessary changes in the validator as below and register form, but I got an error.

```
namespace App\Actions\Fortify;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\CreatesNewUsers;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream;

class CreateNewUser implements CreatesNewUsers
{
    use PasswordValidationRules;

    /**
     * Validate and create a newly registered user.
     *
     * @param  array  $input
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    public function create(array $input)
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'user_email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'user_password' => $this->passwordRules(),
            'terms' => Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature() ? ['required', 'accepted'] : '',
        ])->validate();

        return User::create([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'phone' => $input['phone'],
            'email' => $input['user_email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($input['user_password']),
            'role' => 5, //1 superadmin and 5 user
            'status' => 1,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Error**

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
> 1054 Unknown column 'user_email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select
> count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `user_email` =
> myemail@xyz.com)

Comment: Read the documentation on the Unique rule: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique. You can pass a 2nd param for the column name in the table, like `'unique:users,email'` or `'unique:users,email_address'`. Use the one that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have use user_email validation with unique:users , the validator is trying to execute query as select count(*) as aggregate from users where user_email = "myemail@xyz.com"
Try to remove unique validation or **provide your database column name as 'unique:users,email' in email validation**.

Comment: If i do 'unique:users,email' it dose not check for unique email. I can entering existing email in users table.